# Gradle/Gradlew keeps failing in a React Native project

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

I've installed gradle using brew. `brew install gradle`. However, something is wrong with the installation. Every time I try to run gradle for example just running `$ gradle` or `$ gradle -q tasks` or whatever I get this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteQuietly(Ljava/io/File;)Z

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Running with stack trace gives this output:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteQuietly(Ljava/io/File;)Z

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteQuietly(Ljava/io/File;)Z
    at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.filesystem.services.GenericFileSystem.<init>(GenericFileSystem.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.filesystem.services.FileSystemServices.createFileSystem(FileSystemServices.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.invoke(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:426)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.access$1200(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:739)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:695)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:537)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:577)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.doGet(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:393)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:374)
    at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.FileSystems.getDefault(FileSystems.java:22)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.IdentityFileResolver.<init>(IdentityFileResolver.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.configuration.DaemonParameters.<init>(DaemonParameters.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.configuration.DaemonParameters.<init>(DaemonParameters.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.Parameters.<init>(Parameters.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.BuildActionsFactory.createAction(BuildActionsFactory.java:56)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.createAction(CommandLineActionFactory.java:242)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:232)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
```

`$ gradle -v` is the only command that works:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.9
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-11-17 07:02:17 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     b463d7980c40d44c4657dc80025275b84a29e31f

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_74 (Oracle Corporation 25.74-b02)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.11.3 x86_64
```

Can anyone suggest why this might be the case? Am I missing some dependencies?

I've tried reinstalling multiple times. Even installed gradle from the android tools.

**build.gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use the gradle wrapper instead? It's the preferred way to build on Android and requires nothing special to be installed ahead of time.

Comment: I'm using react-native. It is responsible for doing everything. However, when I run `react-native run-android` I get the same error. That's where this whole thing started. In fact, it does use gradlew but, something is causing it to fail.

Comment: If it uses the gradlew in the project, then you might want to *uninstall* brew's version so there is no possible conflict.  You might also want to be clear in the title or up front that you're using react native.

Comment: Done. Removed brew version of gradle. Still the same issue.

Comment: Hmm, it would seem you're probably fetching conflicting versions of commons.io dependency. Can you post your build.gradle?

Comment: @RaGe added `build.gradle` above

Comment: There should be more build.gradle files in your sub modules?

Comment: @RaGe yes, I created a gist with them: https://gist.github.com/winkerVSbecks/9f33b6b03802a2ccc5d0

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had an outdated version of `org.apache.commons.io` in `Library/Java/Extensions`. I simply replaced it with a new version and it works.

Not sure if I even need to have something in `Library/Java/Extensions`.